# Unresolved reference in class method

Tags: python, function, scope

I don't think it is because of the scope of the function, but I get a

> Unresolved reference at get_all_predicates(examples).count(predicate_list[0])

inside `get_entropy_of_attributes(examples, predicate_list)` function in my class `Tree`:

```
class Tree:

    def get_examples(examples, attributes):
        for value in examples:
            yield dict(zip(attributes, value.strip().replace(" ", "").split(',')))

    def get_all_predicates(examples):
        return [d['Predicate'] for d in examples]

    def get_entropy_of_attributes(examples, predicate_list):
        get_all_predicates(examples).count(predicate_list[0])
        return 0

    examples = list(get_examples(all_examples, name_of_attributes))

    predicate_list = list(set(get_all_predicates(examples)))

    get_entropy_of_attributes(examples, predicate_list)
```

`all_examples` is a list of dictionary and `name_of_attributes` is a list, that holds values imported from a text file.

```
all_examples = [{'P_Length': '1.4', 'P_Width': '0.2', 'Predicate': 'I-setosa', 'Sepal_Width': '3.5', 'S_Length': '5.1'}, ...]

name_of_attributes = ["Check","P-Width"]
```

Any help?

Comment: What are `all_examples`, `name_of_attributes`?

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of `all_examples` and `name_of_attributes`?

Comment: I can't get your code running and thus can't reproduce the error. Can you try to give one running example of your code by including `all_examples` and `name_of_attributes` to your code example?

Comment: Please try to give one running example which leads to your error. Make a new file, copy the example lines in there and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @bastelflp just made the changes again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103429/discussion-between-bastelflp-and-clint-whaley).

Answer (score 8):

Classes do not have scopes, only namespaces. This means that functions defined within them cannot see other class variables automatically.

```
class Foo(object):
    var = 1              # lets create a class variable
    def foo():
        print(var)       # this doesn't work!
```

To access a class variable, you need use attribute syntax: either `Foo.var` (to access via the class) or, if you're writing an instance method, with `self.var` (to access via the current instance, which will be passed in as the first argument).

```
class Bar(object):
    var = 1
    def bar1():
        print(Bar.var) # works
    def bar2(self):
        print(self.var) # also works, if called on an instance, e.g. `Bar().bar2()`
```

With this kind of setup you can *almost* fix your current code (but not quite).

```
def get_entropy_of_attributes(examples, predicate_list):
    Tree.get_all_predicates(examples).count(predicate_list[0])     # name the class
    return 0
```

If you call this after the class is fully initialized, it will work without any exceptions (though it's implementation seems a bit nonsensical). However, it doesn't work when you call it to define a class variable, as your current code does. That's because the class object is only created and bound to the class name *after* all of the class body has been run.

I think the fix for that is probably to redesign your class in a more conventional way. Rather than having class variables set up based on various globals (like `all_examples`), you should probably create instances of your class by passing in arguments to the constructor and making the other variables you calculate from them instance attributes. I'd try to write it out, but frankly I don't understand what you're doing well enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call class methods, you have to call them with `self`, e.g.

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_all_predicates(self):
        print('asd')

    def do_something(self):
        self.get_all_predicates()  # working
        get_all_predicates()  # → Unresolved reference

test = myClass()
test.do_something()
```

See [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes#Creating_a_Class) for examples for Python classes.